# Importing CSV data for table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I created tables for a database in PGadmin (postgreSQL). The first three tables were created and the data was imported successfully. However, I am attempting to import the data for the fourth table (called: location table) from the corresponding CSV and I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "location_id" of relation "location table" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, null, null).
CONTEXT:  COPY location table, line 1380: ",,,,"
```

I am right clicking on the table under 'schema' in PGadmin and selecting 'import/export' rather than writing the code in the console for this import.

The problem is that I have changed all the columns from 'not null' selected, to de-selected. But I still get this error. The error is on line 1380 of my CSV file, but my last line of data is 1379. So, line 1380 should be blank anyways...

Comment: It sounds like the line 1380 exists and is ",,,,". If so go into your csv file by opening a text editor and try to remove any extra character (carriage return, ...) after the line 1379, then save the file and retry the import with `COPY`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that did it. I wasn't seeing any commas in excel but they were present in the text editor.

Comment: If you found a solution to your question, please consider submitting it as an answer and marking it as correct.